# Finding all vectors $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{Z}_{2021^2}^3$ such $x_1x_2x_3 \equiv 43 \;(\text{mod } 2021^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am trying to find all vectors $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{Z}_{2021^2}^3$ that satisfies following condition
$$x_1x_2x_3 \equiv 43 \;(\text{mod } 2021^2)$$
Since $2021^2  = 43^2 * 47^2$ and $43, 47$ are coprime numbers may be we can use chinese reminder theorem someway?But it's about linear equations, so i have no idea how to move next.

Comment: In any case, the CRT is for linear congruences, which this is not.

Comment: I suggest starting by solving $x_1x_2x_3\equiv 1$.  After all, if you have any particular solution to your desired congruence, we can get more by multiplying it by a product that gives $1$.  Also, might not be a bad idea to do the analogous problem for a smaller number, like $(3\times 5)^2$.  Just to see how the computation plays out.

Comment: @lulu so if for example i find all triples $v_j \in \mathbb{Z}_{2021^2}$ such that vector $v_j = (v_j^1, v_j^2, v_j^3)$ satisfies condition $v_j^1 v_j^2 v_j^3 \equiv 1 \; (\text{mod } 2021^2)$, so all my solutions will be  $(43v_j^1, v_j^2, v_j^3)$?

Comment: Of course not.  $(1,43,1)$ is also a solution, for instance.  It may be the case that every solution is of one of the forms $(43a,b,c), (a,43b,c), (a,b,43c)$ where $abc\equiv 1$ but I am not sure of that.  In any case, these solutions are a good starting point.  Solving the problem with $(3\times 5)^2$ instead of the larger number should reveal all the patterns.

Comment: @lulu but you can still count the solutions to $$x_1x_2x_3\equiv 43\pmod{43^2}$$ and $$x_1x_2x_3\equiv 43\pmod{47^2}$$ and then multiply the results due to CRT.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Is it so clear how to do the lift?

Comment: Yes, it is. @lulu

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Ok.  Haven't really thought about it, so perhaps it is straight forward.

Comment: @lulu but if we have such vector $v_j$ that $(43v_j^1, v_j^2, v_j^3)$ is a solution, so the vector $(v_j^2, 43v_j^1, v_j^3)$ is a solution and the vector $(43^{-1}v_j^2, 43v_j^1, v_j^3)$ is a vector from our set, so it seems that we can , multiply only by $(43, 1, 1)$?

Comment: I general, if $m,n$ are relatively prime and $p$ is an integer polynomial, the number of solutions to $p(\vec x)\equiv 0\pmod{mn}$ is the product of the number of solutions modulo $m$ and $n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that's very interesting fact!I will try to think about it. As i understand, we just should myltiply pairwiase all solutions, to get all?

Comment: Not multiply, solve the Chinese remainder theorem problem. If $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is a solution modulo $m$ and $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ is a solution modulo $n$ then we solve the CRT problems: $$x_i\equiv a_i\pmod m\\x_i\equiv b_i\pmod n$$ for $i=1,2,3$ to get a solution modulo $mn.$ @NeoFanatic

Comment: Convince yourself that, given any two units $x,y,$ you get exactly one $z$ so that $xyz\equiv 43\pmod{2021^2}.$ That $z$ is not a unit, and you can place it in any $x_1,x_2,x_3.$ Show this gives all solutions.